# Use ffmpeg to create an audio file from another audio file

Tags: ffmpeg, ffmpeg-filters

I’ve got an opus audio file that’s 10 seconds long. I need to create another, shorter opus file call File1.opus from the 10 second file.
i.e.

Start offset: 3 seconds

Length: 2 seconds

[image: extract file]

Is it possible to create another opus audio file, from an existing opus audio file using ffMpeg?

If so, what command line would I use?

Many thanks

Comment: See the linked question and https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking, basically `ffmpeg -ss 3 -i input.opus -t 2 -c copy output.opus`